# Weird ORA-01858 exception with Oracle/oci_connect/PHP (cache?)

Tags: php, oracle, caching, oracle-call-interface

I am using a PHP script (copied below) I wrote to retrieve data from different schemas of a given Oracle database using the oci functions. Yesterday, I noticed an issue which is 100% reproducible so far and hard for me to understand.

Here's the problem : I have a simple query ("select * from table where id = '42'") and two schemas S1 and S2. First I connect to the DB, then for each schema, I change the current_schema and execute the query.
If I do this on S1, it returns 0 result  which is fine.
If I do this on S2, it returns 2 results which is fine.
If I do this on S1 then S2, it returns 0 result on S1 (which is fine) and I get a 
`1858 - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected` error when trying to execute the query on S2. The corresponding non-numeric character seems to be the '*' from the "select *".

As I was suspecting Oracle cache issues, I decided to append a random comment at the end of the query before executing it. This does solve the issue.
This is pretty hackish and might be wrong for performances reasons.

As I couldn't manage to reproduce this issue in SQL developer, the issue might also come from my code itself but the fact that the random suffix fixes the issue let me think that the Oracle cache is doing wrong things.

So here's my code : the first part contains useful functions to wrap the oci functions, the second part is an actual run of few different tests : BUG is the buggy scenario (ORA-01858), RAND is the scenario with random suffix (fine), SCHEMA_1 is the scenario with just the first schema (0 result : fine), SCHEMA_2 is the scenario with just the second schema (2 results : fine), SAME_SCHEMA is the scenario with the second schema twice (2 results twice : fine).

```
<?php

function db_trigger_error($e) // http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php
{
    $message =
        "\n<pre>\n" .
        htmlentities($e['code']) . " - " .
        htmlentities($e['message']) . " : \n" .
        htmlentities(str_replace(array("\r\n","\t"),array("  "," "),$e['sqltext'])) .
        sprintf("\n%" . ($e['offset']+1) . "s", "^") .
        "\n</pre>\n";
    throw new Exception($message);
}

function execute_query($conn,$query,$fetch_wanted,&$fetch,&$result)
{
    echo($query . "; ...<br>\n");

    // PARSE
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    if (!$stid) { db_trigger_error(oci_error($conn)); }
    $type = oci_statement_type($stid); 

    // EXECUTE
    $exe = oci_execute($stid);
    if (!$exe) { db_trigger_error(oci_error($stid)); }

    // FETCH ARRAY RESULT
    $update = oci_num_rows($stid);
    $fetch = $fetch_wanted  ?
        oci_fetch_all($stid, $result,null,null,OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_COLUMN) :
        0;

    // FREE STUFF
    oci_free_statement($stid);
    echo(" ... returned $fetch row" . ($fetch>1?'s':'') . " and updated/inserted/deleted $update row" . ($update>1?'s':'') . " ($type)<br>\n");
}

function connect_db(&$conn,$username,$password,$connec_string)
{   
    echo("Connecting to username/password@connec_string<br>\n");
    $conn = oci_connect($username,$password,$connec_string);
    if (!$conn) { db_trigger_error(oci_error()); }
    echo("Connected to Server " . oci_server_version($conn) . " with Client version " . oci_client_version($conn) . "<br>\n");
}

function close_connect_db($conn)
{
    if ($conn)
    {
        echo("Connection closed<br>\n");
        oci_close($conn);
    } else 
    {
        echo("No connection to close<br>\n");
    }
}


$username="USERNAME";
$password="PASSWORD";
$connec_string="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HOST)(PORT=PORT)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SERVICE)))";
$query="select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'";

foreach(array('BUG','RAND','SCHEMA_1','SCHEMA_2','SAME_SCHEMA') as $testCase)
{
    echo "Start $testCase<br>\n";
    $schemas=($testCase=='SCHEMA_1') ?    array('S1') :
             ($testCase=='SCHEMA_2') ?    array('S2') :   
             ($testCase=='SAME_SCHEMA') ? array('S2','S2') :
                                          array('S1','S1');

    connect_db($conn,$username, $password, $connec_string);
    foreach($schemas as $schema)
    {
        $suffix=($testCase=='RAND') ? ' --' . rand() : '';
        $query_schema="alter session set current_schema=$schema";
        try 
        {
            execute_query ($conn,$query_schema,   false,$fetch,$result,false);
            execute_query($conn, $query . $suffix,true, $fetch,$result,false);
        }  catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
            $fetch=0;
        }
    }
    close_connect_db($conn);
    echo "End $testCase<br>\n";
}
?>
```

And the corresponding output is :

```
Start BUG
Connecting to username/password@connec_string
Connected to Server Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning and Data Mining options with Client version 10.2.0.3.0
alter session set current_schema=S1; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
alter session set current_schema=S2; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'; ...

Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected in /users/myself/public_html/ProofOfConcept.php on line 25
Caught exception:
1858 - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected : 
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'
       ^
Connection closed
End BUG

Start RAND
Connecting to username/password@connec_string
Connected to Server Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning and Data Mining options with Client version 10.2.0.3.0
alter session set current_schema=S1; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000' --1458191218; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
alter session set current_schema=S2; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000' --849888503; ...
... returned 2 rows and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
Connection closed
End RAND

Start SCHEMA_1
Connecting to username/password@connec_string
Connected to Server Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning and Data Mining options with Client version 10.2.0.3.0
alter session set current_schema=S2; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'; ...
... returned 2 rows and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
alter session set current_schema=S2; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'; ...
... returned 2 rows and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
Connection closed
End SCHEMA_1

Start SCHEMA_2
Connecting to username/password@connec_string
Connected to Server Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning and Data Mining options with Client version 10.2.0.3.0
alter session set current_schema=S2; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'; ...
... returned 2 rows and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
alter session set current_schema=S2; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'; ...
... returned 2 rows and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
Connection closed
End SCHEMA_2

Start SAME_SCHEMA
Connecting to username/password@connec_string
Connected to Server Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning and Data Mining options with Client version 10.2.0.3.0
alter session set current_schema=S2; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'; ...
... returned 2 rows and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
alter session set current_schema=S2; ...
... returned 0 row and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (ALTER)
select * from TABLE t where t.T_ID = '035DA31100000000'; ...
... returned 2 rows and updated/inserted/deleted 0 row (SELECT)
Connection closed
End SAME_SCHEMA
```

Is anyone aware of this issue ? If there a proper fix on the DB side ? Is the use of a random comment as a suffix bad ?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit to add partial investigation**

This was done under the good advises from Justin Cave.

I have now updated the PHP code so that I can have a way to retrieve the sql_id based on a random token with `select * from v$sql where sql_text like '%random_part'` so that I can then get the query plan with `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor('sql_id'))` . In the 'RAND' scenario, this random part is different the two times we run the select query, in the other scenarios, the random part is kept for the different runs of the query.

We then get :

- For the RAND scenario

`select * from v$sql where sql_text like '%random_part'` returns 1 row.
The corresponding query plan is

```
        Plan hash value: 2841037776

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Id  | Operation                   | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                            |       |       |     1 (100)|          |
  |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE                      |     1 |   283 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
  |*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_T_ID                     |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Predicate Information (identified by operation id):             
   ---------------------------------------------------

       2 - access("BFP"."T_ID"='035DA31100000000')
```

- For the buggy scenario :

`select * from v$sql where sql_text like '%random_part'` returns 2 rows with the same SQL_ID. The different parts of the rows are : END_OF_FETCH_COUNT (resp 1 and 0), PARSE_CALLS (resp 1 and 0), BUFFER_GETS (resp 4 and 3), OPTIMIZER_COST (resp 2 and 1), PARSING_SCHEMA_ID (resp 193 and 203), PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME (resp S1 and S2), CHILD_NUMBER (resp 0 and 1), CPU_TIME (resp 7598 and 4093), ELAPSED_TIME (the same), CHILD_ADDRESS (weird things).
The corresponding query plan is

```
 Plan hash value: 2841037776

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Id  | Operation                   | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                            |       |       |     2 (100)|          |
  |   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE                      |     5 |  1535 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
  |*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_T_ID                     |     5 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Predicate Information (identified by operation id):             
   ---------------------------------------------------

       2 - access("BFP"."T_ID"='035DA31100000000')
```

It seems like the same query plan is used.

Comment: Is `TABLE` actually a table rather than a view or some other database object?  What is the data type of `T_ID` in both schemas?  What is the query plan of a query that is working vs. a query that is failing?  The error you're getting implies that there is an implicit data type conversion taking place that is failing.  My wager is that you are getting different query plans where one plan involves applying the implicit conversion before filtering out the row and another involves applying the implicit conversion after filtering out the row.  The latter query will work, the former will error out.

Comment: I think `TABLE` is an actual table (I can see it with `select * from all_tab_cols where owner = 'S1' and table_name like 'TABLE';`).

`T_ID` is a nullable CHAR(16) on both schema.

As I couldn't reproduce on SQL Developer, I don't know how to get the query plan for the failing case.

Comment: What does `select object_type from all_objects where object_name = 'TABLE` and owner = 'S1'` return?

Comment: Object_type is `TABLE` on both schemas.

Comment: Using the random comment, you can look up the `SQL_ID` of the query in `V$SQL` (`GV$SQL` if this is a RAC database), i.e. `select sql_id, sql_text from v$sql where sql_text like '%<<random comment>>%'`.  Then you can get the query plan `select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( <<sql_id>> ))`.

Comment: This is brilliant! Let me try this and thanks in advance for the help you provided me.

Comment: I added the results of your comments in the initial message. Thanks again.

Comment: @JustinCave I followed your ideas but I don't really know what is the next step for me. Is the "buggy" result what I should actually be expected ? Is my only solution to prefix all my queries before executing them ? Thanks